# Connect PS4 and Macbook together to analog speakers

Tags: audio, analog, macbook

I would like to connect my PS4 and Macbook Air together to analog audio speakers and easy work with that without switching wires all the time. PS4 has only Digital Output Audio (Toslink) and Macbook air has USB, 3.5mm.

I had an idea to buy Digital to Analog converter to convert Toslink to analog. Good at this point my PS4 connected to speakers. But macbook air still not. To connect macbook I will use 3.5mm to analog converter and connect them to tulip splitter that will be connected to Digital to Analog converter. By that approach I guess I can join two signals from PS4 and Macbook and will not switch wires.

Before I was search for a ready to use solution but was unlucky there. To buy a speakers with Toslink and USB support looks to much expensive. May I can found some device that will aggregate USB, 3.5mm, Toslink and with simple analog output?

Digital to Analog converter - www.ebay.com/bhp/digital-to-analog-audio-converter
Speakers - Microlab FC330 2.1 Multimedia Speakers
3.5mm to Analog converter - www.monoprice.com/product?p_id=666
Tulp splitter (2 items) - www.televersum.nl/splitters/tulp-splitter/p-1a/AC016G--tulp-splitter%2C-2x-contra-tulp-naar-1x-tulp-male-verguld.html

Answer (score -1):

I have a "soundbar" that has 3.5mm input, Toslink, Coax, Bluetooth, RCA and something digital to hook up with a TV set.

That's enough to get a few things hooked up with it without replugging.  Maybe check what's on offer with a useful number of input options.

I suspect that you'll get away cheaper and with less hassle than when trying to juggle with all sort of external gizmos.

Comment: which one do you have?